# mysql error :error in sql syntax

Tags: php, mysql

i want to insert some lines of text(paragraph) in database that is coming from wikipedia page..but mysql is showing this error when i try to insert the data in db:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's capital." can anyone help me to fix this problem..
here is what i have done so far...

```
 <?php
    $loc=$_POST["new"];
    $url1 ="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=".$loc;
    $opf = file_get_contents($url1);
    $data = json_decode($opf, true);
    $titles = array();
    foreach ($data['query']['pages'] as $page) {
    $des = $page['extract'];

    }
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     } 
    mysql_select_db("location", $con);
    $url = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia";
    echo $sql="INSERT INTO `search`(`id`, `name`, `text`) VALUES ('$loc', '$des');";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
    echo "1 record added";
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: 3 fields but only 2 values. if id is auto inc, just leave it out

Comment: no echo before `$sql=`...

Comment: And a SQL injection vulnerability that is also causing your error

Comment: sql injection vulnerability? how to fix it?
@Dagon yes id is autoincrement..thats why

Comment: "thats why" im doing it wrong?

Comment: you mean to say i should remove 'id' from the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should escape data before entering it into a database. The problem you have is the apostrophe is ending the SQL query on `'$loc'` so the query actually reads:

```
... VALUES ('Giant's Capital',
```

Syntax highlight should indicate why that's a problem :)

Use something like: `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape your `$_POST` data before inputting.

```
$loc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['new']);
```

Comment: means to replace
$loc=$_POST["new"]; 
with
$loc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['new']);   ???

Comment: Yep, that's just me keeping variables the same. Force of habit. Will update answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't explain why it should work

You have 3 fields and 2 values.

> doesn't fix their error

Yes, it does.

> uses obsolete code, and is wide open to SQL injections

It isn’t my code. I am adapting OPs code, I am not trying to write it from scratch. Also, I guess, you forgot to mention that mysql function is deprecated since 5.5

Further, although the fact that the code is SQL injectable is good to mention it does not in my opinion constitute an actual answer. It's a comment at best. ie. "hey btw did you know you misspelled a word?" or some such. An editorial nitpick. If questions are going to be closed as duplicates of SQL injection questions then 80% of the questions here would have to be closed as dupes.

If the OPs wants to know about SQL injection please refer to this [site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Oh, btw,this is the code:

```
<?php
$loc=$_POST["new"];
$url1 ="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=".$loc;
$opf = file_get_contents($url1);
$data = json_decode($opf, true);
$titles = array();
foreach ($data['query']['pages'] as $page) {
$des = $page['extract'];

}
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) { 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 } 
mysql_select_db("location", $con);
$url = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia";
echo $sql="INSERT INTO `search`(`name`, `text`) VALUES ('$loc', '$des');";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't explain *why* it should work, doesn't fix their error, uses obsolete code, and is wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: Thank you @JohnConde for you constructive feedback. I edited my answer, I hope this fulfil your expectations.